# Python: Merging 2 Column in 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

So I am writing a python script using xlsxwriter which imports a data from .xml and write it to .xlsx

My current sheet with column A & B is below:

```
Path    Line

path1   123
path2   234
path3   333
```

and i want output like this with Column A, B and C:

```
Path    Line    Merged
path1   123     path1:123
path2   234     path2:234
path3   333     path3:333
```

I am doing something like below but it only merge 1 cell at a time and copy it to whole column. I want to apply the same formula to whole column:

```
                worksheet.write("A" + str(i), f.filename, cf)
                worksheet.write("B" + str(i), f.line, cf)
                worksheet.write("C" + str(i), '=CONCATENATE(A2, ":",B2)', cf)
```

My current code output give something like this which is not satifying my need:

```
Path    Line    Merged
path1   123     path1:123
path2   234     path1:123
path3   333     path3:123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use var i in your statement:

`worksheet.write("C" + str(i), f'=CONCATENATE(A{i}, ":",B{i})', cf)`